# Preciso criar uma coluna com o ln de uma variável no mesmo data frame

Tags: data.frame, r

Tenho uma série de dados por exemplo PIB e preciso criar uma coluna ao lado dela com a variável lnPIB, como faço no R?

Answer (score 4):

Basta fazer:

```
bd <- data.frame(PIB = PIB)
bd$lnPIB <- log(bd$PIP)
```

Pronto! Seu `data.frame` chamado `bd` agora possui uma coluna com o valor do logaritmo do PIB.

Comment: Obrigado Daniel Falbel.